# Plot a function of multiple variables, with all but one are fixed

Tags: plotting

I have a function of multiple variables that I want to plot. The function is a bit complicated as this

```
GN[k_, p_] := (2 - p + sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/(2*
  sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])*(((p + sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/2)^
 k ) + (p - 2 + sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/(2*
  sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])*(((p - sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/2)^k)

FDN[f_, l_, L_, N_] := (1 - (f^2) * GN[l - 1, f]/(L + 1))*log[(1 - f) N]/log[N]
```

I want to fix the value of all variable but $f$ and plot $FDN$ in that scenario. What I did is as following

```
Plot[FDN[f, 2, 10, 10000], {f, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> Automatic]
```

But what i get is totally unexpected, there is no plot at all!

[image: result]

So what did I do wrong? Can you please help me fix it?
Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica uses UppserCase first letter for its commands (so `log` should be `Log` and `sqrt` should be `Sqrt`. Also `N` is special command in Mathematica.

```
gn[k_, p_] := (2 - p + Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/(2*Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])*
 (((p + Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/2)^
     k) + (p - 2 + Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/
       (2*Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])*(((p - Sqrt[4 p - 3 p^2])/2)^k)

fdn[f_, l_, L_, n_] := (1 - (f^2)*gn[l - 1, f]/(L + 1))*Log[(1 - f)n]/Log[n]

Plot[fdn[f, 2, 10, 10000], {f, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. not good idea to use `l` as variable name, looks like `1`